# How does one get the UV Index for a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, weather, weather-api

I'm looking to make an iphone/android/windows phone app that uses the UV index for the day. Does anyone know how I can get the UV Index for the day? Probably through an API.

I looked into wunderground and accuweather and they seem to have it but the prices are extreme for an independent developer.

All the other weather apis I have contacted don't support UV Index. Does anyone know of any weather APIs that do have UV Index?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to Google "uv index web services"?

Comment: Yes I have. I'll try and get a list of all the weather apis that came up that DON'T have UV Index.

Comment: Might be worth asking on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I looked into World Weather Online, Forecast.io, HamWeather, NWS, and GeoWeatherOnline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be a "weather API", but sounds like what you're looking for (give the sparse details):

http://www.epa.gov/enviro/facts/services.html#uvindex

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I googled "UV Index weather API" and found all the ones I listed in the comment above and they were all paid. If I google what you said using web service, the first link is the one you mentioned. That seems to do what I want, I just wanted to be able to get the UV Index by location. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [OpenUV - Global UV Index Forecast API](https://www.openuv.io).